# How to print the returned value of a asp button OnClick button in a given ID at a ID?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am submitting a following form:

```
 <td colspan="2">
  <asp:TextBox Width="100%" Height="200px" ID="NoteTextBox" CssClass="tb_sm"  Style="text  align:left"
     runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
 <tr><td align="right"> <asp:Button ID="Done" runat="server" Text="Done" OnClick="Done_click"/></td>

 public string Done_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        String a = NoteTextBox.Text;
        // on the basis of that value i have to return a string
          if(a == "xyz") {retrun "Ok"}
          else {return "nop"}
      }
```

From `Done_click` method a string is return on the basis of some conditions, What i am not getting is to print the returned value at the given `ID=NoteTextBox`.

How should i do that?

Comment: post your Done_click event code

Comment: Are you saying you want to set the textbox with the ID "NoteTextBox" to have the value that is returned from Done_click?

Comment: @WaqarJanjua Done! Just write a sudo code, In actually it is very big That's why i have to do in server side

Comment: @ianpgall Check the updated section of code :)

Comment: You can't return a value from an event handler.

Comment: That doesn't help. I'm asking what you want it to actually do. Why are you returning a value from an onclick method? The onclick methods shouldn't have a return value, and instead perform some operation, such as setting the value of something. What do you want to happen when you click the button? The Done_click function will run, but then what do you want to do with the return value?

Comment: @ianpgall In actual situation, I am taking input from a user in the given text box, After that i want to check it whether the input value present in database or not. The database is huge, so i want to load the data in client side. Now if the data entered by user is present in table then it shows on the text box "Data is already present. Enter the new one"

Comment: I posted an answer that hopefully helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try it.

```
public string Done_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String a = NoteTextBox.Text;
    // on the basis of that value i have to return a string
      if    (a == "xyz") 
      {
            form1.Controls.Add( new Literal( { ID = "Literal1", Text = a } ) );
                or 
           Response.Write(a); // It will write at the top of the page so use above code
      }
      else 
       {
            form1.Controls.Add( new Literal( { ID = "Literal1", Text = "nop" } ) );
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Response.Write() in order to test your return;

```
public string Done_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        String a = NoteTextBox.Text;
        // on the basis of that value i have to return a string
          if(a == "xyz") {Response.Write(a);}
          else {Response.Write("nop");}
      }
```

You print on Response stream, top of your screen

You can also add label to your screen, and set value

```
LabelTest.Text = a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in order to print values in asp.net, like php you use `echo`. While in asp.net you have to use `Response.Write()` Method;

```
String a = NoteTextBox.Text;
if(String.Compare(a, "xys") == 0)
{
       Response.Write("ok");
}
else
{
    Response.Write("Not ok");
}
```

you will see the output at the top of the page.
And I have also mentioned String.Compare() which return 0 if successful. It is basically .net String class method.